# calling the match function of generic usb device driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I was going through [generic.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/generic.c) related to USB subsystem in Linux Kernel. The usb device driver(usb_generic_driver) was registered by usb core(usb_init).

The usb_device_driver structure is having id_table(struct usb_device_id *id_table) member, but I didn't find in the source where this id_table was filled and assigned in usb_generic_driver structure.

```
struct usb_device_driver {
   const char *name;

   bool (*match) (struct usb_device *udev);
   int (*probe) (struct usb_device *udev);
   void (*disconnect) (struct usb_device *udev);

   int (*suspend) (struct usb_device *udev, pm_message_t message);
   int (*resume) (struct usb_device *udev, pm_message_t message);
   const struct attribute_group **dev_groups;
   struct usbdrv_wrap drvwrap;
   const struct usb_device_id *id_table;
   unsigned int supports_autosuspend:1;
   unsigned int generic_subclass:1;
};
```

If there is no "id_table" for generic driver then how the match function(usb_generic_driver_match) is called. If id_table is defined for generic driver, can you help me to find the id_table for the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I don't understand your doubts. The USB Generic Driver is by definition **generic**. It means that if no driver found by real matching (with ID tables in the individual drivers) it will be used.

Device matching is first happening on [bus level](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/driver.c#L2004). Which is covered by [`usb_device_match()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/driver.c#L820) call that checks first is it device or interface and then tries match by ID table if present. Since for generic driver it does not have match table, but has specific [`->match()` callback](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/usb/core/driver.c#L839) that is called as a last resort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Now from your explanation I got clarity that generic driver's match function(usb_generic_driver_match) will be called when there is no matching id_table driver found.
But in the generic driver's match function(usb_generic_driver_match) again it is calling driver iterator function(bus_for_each_drv) and matching for other drivers. I think already same was done in usb_device_match function before calling generic drivers match function.

Comment: USB is hotpluggable bus and many scenarios are possible. That's why it needs to rematch often for the changes (btw, device IDs is subject to change even without physical detaching of the device).

Comment: because of the scenarios like changing the functionality at runtime in USB composite devices.